# Binding a datatable to a checkbox list

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net

I have a database with criteria in it, I use SQL to extract all criteria from the database into a data table but when I bind the data it doesn't display in my checkbox? What am I doing wrong?

```
private void Criteria_Load()
{
   string query = "Select CRITERIA From EF_CONTACT_FIELDS";
   cbCriteria.DataTextField = "CRITERIA";
   cbCriteria.DataSource = GetData(query);
   cbCriteria.DataBind();
}

<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbCriteria" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Comment: Add before `DataBind()`, `cbCriteria.DataTextField = "CRITERIA";`

Comment: @mww well spotted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mention `DataTextField` to show the selected data.

If you have ID field for CRITERIA and want to get the selected value, you can use, `cbCriteria.DataValueField = "CRITERIA_ID";` (if any)

```
private void Criteria_Load()
    {
        string query = "Select CRITERIA From EF_CONTACT_FIELDS";
        cbCriteria.DataTextField = "CRITERIA";
        cbCriteria.DataSource = GetData(query);
        cbCriteria.DataBind();
    }
```

Note : **DataTextField** should be assigned before **DataBind**.